# Worse performance with constexpr?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, constexpr

I am trying to evaluate performance difference by using `constexpr`. I am using the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

constexpr double factorial(int n) {

    return n==0?1:n*factorial(n-1);
}

main() {
    double a=0;
    for(int i=0;i<10000000;i++) {
        a+=factorial(100);

    }
    cout<<a<<endl;
}
```

I tried out two versions of the above program, one with the factorial function as `constexpr`, and one without. I expected to see the `constexpr` version perform better during runtime, but it in fact, runs slower. Here are the measurements (in seconds) from 4 trials each:

Without `constexpr`:

2.691, 2.835, 2.768, 2.748

With `constexpr`:

2.910, 2.920, 2.903, 2.910

Could someone explain the reason behind this? Am I using `constexpr` wrong? I am using g++ 4.9.1, and I used the O3 optimization flag.

EDIT: The code originally assigned the factorial to `a`. It has been updated to add up the results, as suggested in the comments. The performance difference still visible though.

Comment: First thing before even considering this benchmark seriously (though maybe not applicable in this case since the times are pretty large) -- your loop does the exact same thing every time. An optimizer might merely skip the work and perform it once. Try summing the factorial and output the result. Second, could you post the assembly?

Comment: I can't really reproduce your results (using GCC 5.2): http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/407a3aa32caaef9e

Comment: [Without constexpr](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxcvVB8sWMHJbmxyZzNXdzRiN1U/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: [With constexpr](http://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxcvVB8sWMHJVnVraXI2RE5DeWM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @melak47, hmm.. I guess I should just try gcc 5.2?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://goo.gl/2wkIJ3), I get the same assembly with and without constexpr even with 4.9.2. (oops, without -O3, though)

Comment: I'm running on a 64-bit machine. Would that make a difference? I'm afraid I do not know much about how compilers do the optimization, so this might be a noob question...

Comment: I do see a lot of diff in the assembly (links in comments above). I can't make much sense out of it though.

Comment: I had a look at the assembly output on clang. It's more or less the same. The function is not being evaluated at compile time. If you change the argument and return type to `long long`, it will be. I suspect the mixing of integer and floating point maths in the constexpr function is preventing it from being a constexpr (possibility of floating point exceptions?)

Comment: @RichardHodges When I do that, I finally see constexpr perform better. But i think 100! is a multiple of 2^(sizeof(long long)), so I see 0 as the result for factorial(100). Could you please write this as an answer so that I could accpet it?

Answer (score 1):

`constexpr` is advantageous when the computation is done at compile-time. However, compilers aren't required to do that unless you require that, by making `a` `constexpr`, for example. At runtime `constexpr` makes no difference for a function.

I get very close results in my tests (delta of ~0.1s), as expected.